# Counting Menu Items of the SubMenu in Typo3

Tags: navigation, typo3, submenu, typoscript

I'm currently trying to create a nav in Typo3, and I need to know the number of items in the submenu of the current menu. But i don't see any possibity in achieving this.

I know about {register:count_menuItems}, but this doesn't really help.

In the first level of the nav I need the number of Items of the second level to put it into the class of the list (4 in this example)

```
wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown mega-menu-4"> | </li>
```

Is it even worth trying or simply not possible?

Thanks :)

Example of the Nav:

```
#Testmenu4
lib.testmenu4 = HMENU
lib.testmenu4 {
entryLevel = 0

1 = TMENU
1 {
    expAll = 1
    wrap = <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> | </ul>
    noBlur = 1

    NO = 1
    NO {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li> | </li>
        stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        ATagTitle.field = title
    }

    IFSUB = 1
    IFSUB {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown mega-menu-4"> | </li>
        wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
        stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        ATagTitle.field = title
        ATagParams = class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"
    }

    ACT = 1
    ACT <.NO

    ACTIFSUB = 1
    ACTIFSUB <.IFSUB
}

2 = TMENU
2 <.1
2 {
    expAll = 1
    wrap = <ul class="dropdown-menu"> | </ul>
    NO {    
        doNotShowLink = 1
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="one-column"> | </li>
    }
    IFSUB = 0
    ACTIFSUB = 0
}

3 = TMENU
3 <.2
3 {
    expAll = 1
    wrap = <ul> | </ul>
    NO {
        doNotShowLink = 0
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="nav-title"> | </li> |*| <li> | </li>
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I would use JavaScript or custom PHP for this... (that's only an opinion, don't know your requirements as you doesn't mention it)

Comment: I'd just render a cObject somehow in the menu entry (`stdWrap.cObject`), and use a `CONTENT` cObject to query the database for all pages with `pid = <current page id>`. This would of course do many database queries, but the results will be cached, so that's not a big problem. The details can be hard to get right though - it would get ugly if you are using mount points or similar things.

Comment: If I understood your question, then this link help you and exactly what you need: http://www.typo3wizard.com/en/snippets/menus/menu-with-recursive-count-of-subpages.html